# Build up of global variables in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an app where I make heavy use of AJAX calls to import partial MVC views into my DOM.

I was noticing some strange sporadic behavior where variables would lose their state.
I was hoping someone could help me confirm my suspicion for why this is happening

Ex I have the following partial view:
JS:

```
--begin script tags
var var1 = 1;
var var2 = 2;
var manager = null;    

$(document).ready(function() 
{
  //Do stuff
  manager = new Manager();
});
--End script tag

<div>
Markup in partial view
</div>
```

The partial view is imported into my dom over and over again if the user clicks a button. It is inserted into the same element everytime, effectively overwriting itself everytime.
My question though is: Could loading this section into the DOM multiple times cause the script block to be added to my DOM multiple times? Does the JS get left behind, once per time the partial view is pulled into the DOM?

The script has been greatly simplified, but one example is that manager can be null, even after it's been initialized. My guess is that it there might be multiple instances in the DOM...

It seems like I can fix the issue by wrapping the whole JS block in a self calling closure, but I wasn't sure if that was necessary... I was wondering if someone has a good explanation for why the closure is needed. My theory is that it prevents a build up in the DOM of multiple versions of the Partial View script block...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a script consisting of a single self-calling closure does not introduce new variables in the global namespace, it only defines a function, then calls it, then promptly forgets about it since it has no external references.

On the other hand, your partial view introduces `var1`, `var2` and `manager` in the global namespace every time you import it, overwriting previous definitions. This might explain the sporadic variable behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: Yes I am thinking this is the issue. Objects like the Manager will change state throughout execution (be initialized etc), Seems like the closure is the proper and safe way to do this.

Comment: Actually, your `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` should serve perfectly well as a closure.

Comment: However, is it safe to assume that var1 and var2 will be overwritten everytime. Is there any chance of duplicates?

Comment: @TGH, duplicates in the global scope? No. Names defined in that scope are mapped to properties of the `window` object. Further definitions will override previous ones.

Comment: But wouldn't it be similar to declaring two variables with the same name in two different places (everytime it gets inserted into the DOM?). It's just hard to see why I need the closure if the variables get overwritten.. I have a measure in place to not allow loading the view again until the previous one is done...

Comment: No, further insertions into the DOM do not count as different places. There is only one global scope.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation makes total sense now. The issue was caused by another bug in my code :-)